# How to append with quotation marks to make it into a string array?

Tags: arrays, swift, append

Successfully read the JSON, parse and append to array.
The result is something like [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7,.....]

How do I parse it in my code so that it becomes
["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7",...]

Any pointers is greatly appreciated.

```
   //****** Parsing to array *********
    var prefList = [JSON]()
    for i in 0..<json["result"].count {
        let tt = json["result"][i]["prefName"]
        prefList.append(tt)
    }
    print(prefList)

    //****** Parsing to array *********
    var prefCodeList = [JSON]()
    for x in 0..<json["result"].count {
        //print(json["result"][i]["prefCode"])
        let nn = json["result"][x]["prefCode"]
        prefCodeList.append(nn)
    }
    print(prefCodeList)
```

Comment: You need to convert the numbers to text. How you do that depends on which language you are using, which unfortunately you don't tell us. Also, such conversions are usually taught during the very first lessons of any programming language course / book / series, so you might want to look there.

Comment: Sorry, I’m using swift 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a combination of map and the String constructor.

`prefCodeList.map(String);  // --> ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"]`.

Pay attention that this will return a new array.

Comment: Can you kindly explain how to implement it?

//MARK: - JSON Parsing
    func updateData(json: JSON) {
        _ = json["result"]
      
        let tempResult = json
        print(tempResult)
        
        //****** Parsing to array *********
        var prefList = [JSON]()
        for i in 0..<json["result"].count {
            //print(json["result"][i]["prefName"])
            let tt = json["result"][i]["prefName"]
            
            prefList.append(tt)
        }
        
        print(prefList)

Comment: @Benny - You can use ```prefCodeList.map { String($0) }``` or if you want the String to be optional, you can use ```prefCodeList.map { Optional(String($0)) }```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I have found the problem. It was in my code.
I've set the var prefList = JSON, all I have to do is to set it to String

Still very interested the .map function.